# Why is AsQueryable() for the class DBSet not in the MSDN documentation?

Tags: .net, dbset, asqueryable

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx) describes the class DBSet.This type implements IQueryable, what means, that it has to have an implementation for AsQueryable(). But in the list in the link I cannot find this method.
Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Probably because `DbSet` implements `IQueryable`, so there's no need to cast it explicitly.

Comment: It's implements `IQueryable` *explicitly*. If you want to use all of the methods (directly or by extensions) on that interface, you have to cast it to that interface first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial answer while hopefully useful was not entirely correct as pointed out by Eli Arbel so I have rewritten it.

The [`DbSet<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx) class has a complicated inheritance hierarchy. Here is a UML diagram showing just part of it.

[image: DbSet inheritance hierarchy]

The method `AsQueryable<TEntity>()` is an extension method defined on `IEnumerable<TEntity>` that converts the `IEnumerable<TEntity>` into an `IQueryable<TEntity>` and as `DbSet<TEntity>` implements `IEnumerable<TEntity>` you are able to use the extension method:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> queryable = myDbSet.AsQueryable();
```

However, it is not very useful because `DbSet<TEntity>` also implements `IQueryable<TEntity>` so calling `AsQueryable()` will simply return the `IQueryable<TEntity>` interface. You might as well write the snippet above as:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> queryable = myDbSet;
```

This behavior is explained in the documentation for [`Queryable.AsQueryable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003(v=vs.110).aspx) which is the documentation you are looking for.

It is correct that the linked documentation page does include a lot of extension methods but as the universe of possible extension methods in principle is unbounded there is no guarantee that all extension methods will be in the list. In particular both `AsQueryable()` and `AsEnumerable()` are missing.

Comment: Thanks. I now really do not know anymore why I even thought AsQueryable should be a member of IQueryable. My question is answered.